# Issue in compiling JRXML through Jaspersoft Studio: Column spacing must be positive

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm designing JRXML in *JasperSoft Studio*. I want the no. of columns in the page to be more. A4 Page Format doesn't suit my needs. So selected 'Custom' Page Format and changed the Width to '1000' and Height to '900'. With these properties when i compile I'm getting the below error message. Can i know what should i do to increase the page width to add more fields as columns.

```
Column spacing must be positive net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign
```

Sample JRXML which is empty :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample_1" language="groovy" pageWidth="1000" pageHeight="900" columnWidth="960" columnSpacing="-39" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="eaebc377-4aaf-4a46-9a9f-ededa4246308">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/menu-compare/field-details/fields]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Have pasted it in the question section.

Comment: can you try changing this line <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/> to  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="2"/> and see if it works

Comment: Still the same error. Looks error is referring to this line
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample_1" language="groovy" pageWidth="1000" pageHeight="900" columnWidth="960" columnSpacing="-39" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="eaebc377-4aaf-4a46-9a9f-ededa4246308">

Comment: changed the columnSpacing over there from -39 to 39. It is working. THank you.

Comment: :) glad that you solved

Comment: I see misalignment in CSV after page-break, what is the solution for this ?

Comment: try playing around with margin values to see what should work

Comment: Margin values are available only in this line.
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample_1" language="groovy" pageWidth="1600" pageHeight="1900" columnWidth="1560" columnSpacing="39" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="eaebc377-4aaf-4a46-9a9f-ededa4246308">

There is no information on page breaks